# How to view c# compiler output of syntactic sugar

Tags: c#, visualization

I'm looking to see if there is a method or tool to view how things like closures or query expressions are created by the c# compiler "under the hood". I've noticed that many blog posts dealing with these issues will have the original code with syntactic sugar and the underlying c# code that the compiler converts that to. So for example with linq and query expressions they would show:

```
var query = from x in myList select x.ToString();
```

then the resulting code would be

```
var query = myList.Select(x=>x.ToString());
```

Is it possible with a tool or do you just have to know how it works from the spec and go from there?

Comment: Resharper can flip between the two forms.

Comment: @Darryl - that sounds more like an answer than a comment...  Get some credit!

Comment: When I understand you correct you want to have a look at the assembled IL code to check what the compilers does make out of it? .NET Reflector is your friend then. It's a little bit unclear, because your example would point to sth. like ReSharper, but you also asks for the compiled code.

Comment: LINQPad can do that (and more), but you'll have to do requests on a supported datasource (sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a user of Resharper, but I'm sure that will work. 
You already seem to know the alternate form of your Linq syntax query. I think that is the answer; Know what you are doing. Read up on it. If you don't know, you are dangerous, and you will go nowhere near my code base. :)

Seriously, this takes a minimum of reading up on, and provides you with immense power in C#. If you are at all interested in your work, you know this.

Comment: Well this is what I thought was the case from the get go. But I wanted to be sure because a tool like that would be very handy for me!

Answer (score 5):

[SharpLab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI4DcyyUAzJjOgMLoDey6bmNUALOgLIAUASnSt2LJO0noiAFwDaAXXQBbAJ4EAzjPQBeZnAA06GEaoBfchKltR1gG4BDAE7piAVwCmT1bvQAzJwB7ZXQAD2lCFXV8LXQNDwAbDwBjbVDsABVAgGUZJyIAcyFLSTNkMyA===) is the tool you are looking for.

From the [site](https://github.com/ashmind/SharpLab), SharpLab shows intermediate steps and results of code compilation. It allows you to see the code as compiler sees it, and get a better understanding of .NET languages.

Comment: SharpLab is awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Resharper can do this conversion (LINQ expression syntax to lambda syntax) for you very easily.

LINQPad has a tab that can show you the lambda expression syntax for a query you enter into it, and it has another tab that disassembles it all the way down to the IL code level. (There's another tab that shows you the SQL that gets generated if you're using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities).

Comment: Well that works for linq but I'm looking for something a little more generic. Something that can show all the syntactic sugar conversions that C# does for you. But Robert's answer is leading me to believe it's not possible. Oh well

Comment: @Matt Phillips: Linqpad is actually a mini-IDE, and you can run any C# code inside of it, and then see the IL that got produced by that code. That's the only way to really understand how much syntactic sugar there is because, for example, `myList.Select(x=>x.ToString())` is itself syntax sugar for `Enumerable.Select(myList, delegate(int x) {return x.ToString();})`, and the delegate closure itself is arguably syntax sugar for creating a class with a single, implicit function and a private reference to the `x` variable.

Comment: Good point. Thats the kind of stuff I was looking for. I think my best bet is definitely to just learn the spec :)

Answer (score 2):

How far under the hood do you want to go?

If you're really interested in seeing what your code looks like after you compile it, you should check out `ildasm.exe`.  This tool will show you the cold, hard, IL, generated when you compile your application. This tool will allow you to open up any of your compiled assemblies are view the real nuts and bolts that are *under the hood*.

Comment: Well I'm not looking quite that far under the hood. Use that linq example i put in the question as a guide. Can I see output that would show me what a query expression looks like after the compiler converts it to the method calls? Or is it like I said, that you have to *know* thats what is going on.